EventSourcePolyfill doesn't receive all data as postman (angular)
i have this problem with EventSourcePolyfill , when i create new notification it doesn't receive any thing but after some number of notifications it receive the previous notifications but also it get truncated
import { EventSourcePolyfill } from 'event-source-polyfill';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

getStream(): Observable<any> {

     return new Observable((observer) => {
    this.eventSource = new EventSourcePolyfill(this.streamUrl, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authToken,
          'organization-id': this.securityDTO.OrganizationId,
        },        
      });

      this.eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
        observer.next(event.data);
      };

      this.eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        this.eventSource?.close();
        this.reconnect(observer);  
      };

      private reconnect(observer: any): void {
    this.getStream().subscribe(observer);
}

and this is how i call it
this.streamService.getStream().subscribe((data: any) => {
  const notification = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data); 
});
  

